# Firebase Cloud Messaging : how to hide app connection infos

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've correctly implemented notification through Firebase Cloud Messaging.
I'm now seeking to how to secure it.
I think it's better to hide connections infos, you know, this firebaseConfig :

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

And the vapid key used with the getToken function :

```
getToken(messaging, {vapidKey: '\_key\_'});
```

How to secure it, prevent attacks to Firebase FCM like sending mass notification or receiving other's personal notifications ?

Comment: "I think it's better to hide connections infos, you know, this firebaseConfig" Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ha, thanks, seen a lot of questions/answer in SO, even seen you answering I think, but not this one :)
Ha, and I've seen you edited my post to add code tags, I'll take care of it.
We've answered to the firebase config infos, what's for the vapid key ?
Thanks !

Comment: From the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#configure_web_credentials_in_your_app) it seems like the VAPID key is also needed in the client-side app. So it's an identification mechanism, not a security mechanism.

Comment: Ok, so finally, what's disturbed me was the fact that for the notification subscription, there's no authentification. 
And for security, we have to apply security rules described here : https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/launch-checklist and here : https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/security-checklist .
Am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, thanks to Frank van Puffelen who answered me, I understood that vapid public key and firebaseConfig infos are used for identification client side, not security/authentification.
Thanks Frank !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).